# How to pass a switch variable?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

```psh
& "$THIS_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY_PATH\New-NuGetPackage.ps1" -PushOptions "$pushOptions" `
    -Verbose -ProjectFilePath $project -PO "$packOptions" -NPFPPTNG
```

So if I provide the command line above in PowerShell the call works correctly.

If I try something like this:

```psh
if ($NoPromptForPushPackageToNuGetGallery) {
    $xtraOptions += " -NPFPPTNG "
}

& "$THIS_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY_PATH\New-NuGetPackage.ps1" -PushOptions "$pushOptions" `
    -Verbose -ProjectFilePath $project -PO "$packOptions" $xtraOptions
```

this fails. How can I pass a switch in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx):

```psh
$xtraOptions = @{}
if ($NoPromptForPushPackageToNuGetGallery) {
    $xtraOptions.Add("NPFPPTNG",$true)
}

& "$THIS_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY_PATH\New-NuGetPackage.ps1" -PushOptions "$pushOptions" -Verbose -ProjectFilePath $project -PO "$packOptions" @xtraOptions
```

If `$xtraOptions` is just an empty hashtable, `@xtraOptions` will simply have no effect on the parameters passed.

---

You could also push all the parameters into the splatting table with a conditional value:

```psh
$nuGetOptions = @{
    PushOptions     = "$pushOptions"
    ProjectFilePath = $project 
    PO              = "$packOptions"
    Verbose         = $Verbose
    NPFPPTNG        = if($NoPromptForPushPackageToNuGetGallery) { $true } else { $false }
}

& "$THIS_SCRIPTS_DIRECTORY_PATH\New-NuGetPackage.ps1" @nuGetOptions
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass boolean values to switch parameters causing them to be set (`$true`) or unset (`$false`):

```
& "New-NuGetPackage.ps1" -PushOptions "$pushOptions" `
  -Verbose -ProjectFilePath $project -PO "$packOptions" `
  -NPFPPTNG:$NoPromptForPushPackageToNuGetGallery
```

Comment: i would much rather not list the options.  splatting seems the best way for me.  tx