# Pass entire hashtable to Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I would like to ask you for an question about passing hashtable to Invoke-Expression.

Iam writing simple E2E monitoring and mentioned hashtable is used as a body containing creds for HTTP form to log jira.
It works for me fine, but from specific reason I would like to create this Invoke-Webrequest dynamically, depending on recieved arguments.
And there is my catch.

Thus, I don't know, how to pass hashtable (other data types are ok, like a string or int) to Invoke Expression.
It is always presented like `System.Collections.Hashtable`

```
$uri = 'https://exdom.com/login.jsp?saml_sso=false'
$method = "POST"
$postParams = @{
    os_username = "username";
    os_password = "password";
    login = "true"
}

$scriptBlock = {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$uri,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)][string]$method,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)][hashtable]$postParams
    )
    $commandFragments = @()
    $commandFragments += "Invoke-WebRequest"
    if ( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('uri')){
        $commandFragments += " -Uri $uri"
    }
    if ( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('method')){
        $commandFragments += " -Method $method"
    }
    if ( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('postParams')){
        $commandFragments += " -Body $postParams"
    }
    $commandFromFragments = $commandFragments -join ''
    (Invoke-Expression -Command $commandFromFragments).Content | Out-File 'c:\tmp\response3.html'
    (Invoke-Expression -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://exdom.com/login.jsp?saml_sso=false -Method POST -Body @(@{'os_username' = 'username@mydomain.com'; 'os_password' = 'mypassword'; 'login' = 'true'})").Content | Out-File 'c:\tmp\response4.html'
    (Invoke-WebRequest -Method $method -Uri $uri -Body $postParams).Content | Out-File 'c:\tmp\response5.html'
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList ($uri, $method, $postParams)
```

Iam missing something basic, I guess.
May I ask you for an advice?

Thanks, Marcel

Comment: Use splatting. `Invoke-Expression` is not needed here.

Comment: `$commandFragments += " -Body $postParams"` <-- this is where it all breaks down, you're coercing the hashtable into a string. Use [splatting and the `&` operator instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873846/how-to-pass-a-switch-variable/30873934#30873934)

Answer (score -1):

Lets talk about whats wrong.

```
$commandFragments += " -Body $postParams"
```

You are turning a HashTable into a string. Which is not possible. So what we can do is convert it into something. Now what should we convert into? **`Invoke-WebRequest -body`**

This can be done with Json. So you could use **`" -Body $($postParams | convertto-json)"`**

But this is only saving the json to a string which still wouldnt work because the Json needs to be in a string inside the command **`Invoke-WebRequest`**. So the fix would be to surround the JSON with single quotes. **`" -Body '$($postParams | ConvertTo-Json)'"`**

We also have some small fixes we can do for efficiency. Like the if statements looking

```
$PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | %{
    switch($_.Key){
        "uri" { $commandFragments += " -Uri $uri" }
        "method" { $commandFragments += " -Method $method" }
        "postParams" { $commandFragments += " -Body '$($postParams | ConvertTo-Json)'" }
    }
}
```

The final product being

```
$uri = 'https://exdom.com/login.jsp?saml_sso=false'
$method = "POST"
$postParams = @{
    "os_username" = "username";
    "os_password" = "password";
    "login" = "true"
}

$scriptBlock = {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$uri,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=2)][string]$method,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)][hashtable]$postParams
    )

    $commandFragments = $("Invoke-WebRequest")
    $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | %{
        switch($_.Key){
            "uri" { $commandFragments += " -Uri $uri" }
            "method" { $commandFragments += " -Method $method" }
            "postParams" { $commandFragments += " -Body '$($postParams | ConvertTo-Json)'" }
        }
    }
    (Invoke-Expression -Command $($commandFragments -join '')).Content | Out-File 'c:\tmp\response3.html'
    (Invoke-Expression -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://exdom.com/login.jsp?saml_sso=false -Method POST -Body @(@{'os_username' = 'username@mydomain.com'; 'os_password' = 'mypassword'; 'login' = 'true'})").Content | Out-File 'c:\tmp\response4.html'
    (Invoke-WebRequest -Method $method -Uri $uri -Body $postParams|ConvertTo-Json).Content
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList ($uri, $method, $postParams)
```